# How to make this switch statement?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

i have a viewcontroller 1 and a viewcontroller 2.
I want to make a switch statement.
If it's an iphone, then go to viewcontroller 1, and if it's an ipad, go to viewcontroller 2.

I know i have to do this code:

```
switch     UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
case .Phone:
// It's an iPhone
case.Pad
// It's an iPad:
case .Unspecified:
// Uh, oh! What could it be?
}
```

But what's next?
Sorry, i know that i'm a beginner, but hope you guys can help me. That would be great.

Comment: What do you want to do push the ViewControllers ??? Or modally prsent them ??? Whats your intention ???

Comment: As you say you are a beginner I strongly suggest you adopt autolayout so that your UI adapts to the device it is running on rather than having specific ViewControllers for the different device families. If you are using storyboards then you can nominate different storyboards for iPhone and iPad if your UI is totally different

Comment: Okay, i did it with different storyboards, thanks guys.